# Selenium-java: I want to write data everytime from webpage to excel always in new row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Selenium-java: I want to write data everytime from webpage to excel always in new row.
Actually i want to print order id in excel and every time it is generating a new order id on a webpage.

Comment: Please look into Apache POI.  It allows you to read/modify excel files using Java https://www.browserstack.com/guide/read-data-from-excel-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a CSV file and append everything in a new line every time. This will help you to create excel much faster.

But the better solution will be to use Apache POI it will have efforts to implement big code.